# how can I plot this with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to use Tikz to draw the image below, I have data for the values of x, y and u/u_b

[image: From Suga Analytical wall function 2006]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: *I have data for the values of x, y and u/u_b* then what you're waiting for, share them!

Comment: If the data cannot be shared, some dummy data with the same structure would also work.

Comment: the data is a set of X,Y,U value , i have tried with XMGRACE but it was complicated to use

Comment: Plotting the columns of a text file is quite simple with `pgfplots`, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83888/how-to-plot-data-from-a-csv-file-using-tikz-and-csvsimple/83929#83929) for an example. Most of your plot could be done with that technique.