# How to add a shaded confidence interval to a pgf plot from a csv file?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Here is the file:
[data](https://easyupload.io/bweb1i)
I can't get the following code to work. Apparently adding and subtracting the rows is the problem. Am I missing something here?

```
 \documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=\linewidth, 
        xmin = 0, xmax = 90,
        ymin = 45, ymax =65,
        xlabel= {Time[s]},
        ylabel={ST},
        error bars/y dir=both, % turn on error bars
        error bars/y explicit]
        %upper line for the interval
        \addplot[name path=upper, fill=none, draw=none] table[col sep=comma, x=pn_T, y expr=\thisrow{pn_ST} + \thisrow{pn_SD}]{data.csv}; 
        %lower line for the interval
        \addplot[name path=lower, fill=none, draw=none] table[col sep=comma, x=pn_T, y expr=\thisrow{pn_ST} - \thisrow{pn_SD}]{data.csv};
        %fill between the lines
        \addplot[green!40] fill between[of=lower and upper];
        %add the two plots 
        \addplot+[ color=blue, mark=., thin, error bars/error bar style={gray}] table[col sep=comma, x=Base_T, y=Base_ST, y error=Base_SD] {data.csv} ;
        \addplot+[ color=green,mark=., thin] table[col sep=comma, x=pn_T, y=pn_ST] {data.csv} ;     
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

I Get the following error when I try to compile the code in my main document:

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point
> number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in ' + '). See the
> PGF Math package documentation for explanation. Type H  for
> immediate help. ... l.13 ...n_ST} +
> \thisrow{pn_SD}]{data/tritonad.csv}; This error message was generated
> by an \errmessage command, so I can't give any explicit help. Pretend
> that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues, and deduce the truth by
> order and method.

Comment: It returns a plot to me, whether it is displayed right or wrong, I am not able to say. Maybe you can be more specific about what exactly is not working the way you expect it do be?

Comment: This is the error I get:
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number,
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in ' + ').
See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.

Comment: Are you sure that use the very same CSV file that you link to above? It seems to me that PGF tries to find a numerical value in column `pn_ST` for the given row but this cell is empty. You should check in your CSV whether there are maybe rows with only empty values.

Comment: You can add `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/handlers/empty number/.code={\pgfmathparse{0}}}` to your preamble. This will tell PGF to handle any empty string as zero. But you should actually look into your CSV file for empty values and set them to `nan` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83735/47927).

Comment: @ Jasper Habicht, I added that line to the document and it solved my problem. I can plot the data now. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the data, `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/handlers/empty number/.code={\pgfmathparse{nan}}}` might be more accurate.